# selection in textview

Tags: android

I have a Text View in my application and I want to select text from 
that text view and i want the starting & ending position of that 
selected text so can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Starting and Ending position may be retrieved with:

```
  int selectionStart = textView.getSelectionStart();
    int selectionEnd = textView.getSelectionEnd();
```

and Selected text may be with:

```
String selectedText = et.getText().substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's any way of programmatically making a selection in a `TextView`.

However, you can get the start and end position of a selection by calling [`TextView.getSelectionStart()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionEnd%28%29), optionally calling `hasSelection()` first if you want.